# DYMO Web Service certificate error

Tags: ssl, dymo

I have an SSL certificate installed on my website and I have intergrated the DYMO Label Printer (using the Dymo Web Service).

The web service is installed on the local machine and connects to `https://localhost:41955/DYMO/DLS/Printing/Check`

Unfortunately, because this runs on HTTPs locally there is a certificate error which then causes the website to show as unsecure.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: I was just about to post an answer to your post about splitting time to 50 and 25 price. Do you want to undelete or should I scrap it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According the DYMO Developer SDK Support Blog there was a bug in versions prior to 8 that causes a security certificate issue for Windows systems:

http://developers.dymo.com/

In that same page they indicate that version 8.6.2.658 fixes the problem with the certificate.

You can download it from the following link: http://labelwriter.com/software/dls/win/DLS8Setup.8.6.2.658.exe

Stop the server and uninstall the previous version before installing the new one to avoid any conflicts, also restart the server if you can after installing, just in case.